# How to add UILable inside the body of the mail

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

i want add add UILabel inside the setMessageBody ( MFMailComposeViewController )

currently i have the following code for setMessageBody.

NSString* emailString =   [NSString stringWithFormat:
 @"Hi...Please click on the below link";

[mailViewController setMessageBody:emailString isHTML:YES];

Pls help me how can i add label in the body of the mail.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

An email body can either be plain text or HTML, you cannot add controls within a message. You should generate HTML to layout your message the way you want it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply...is it possible to add label on the image attched with the mail

Comment: You would have to manually draw your text into a drawing context and generate the image file.